# How to get the UTC representation of start and end of a day interpreted in a certain timezone using date-fns/date-fns-tz?

Tags: typescript, date, datetime, date-fns

For example, if we have the date "07-15-2023" in "America/Los_Angeles" time zone, I want to get the UTC representations of "07-15-2023 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" and "07-15-2023 23:59:59 America/Los_Angeles". How can I do this?

I have the second half of the problem which is trivial which is to call `zonedTimeToUtc(startOfDay(localDate), timezone)`

The issue is getting `localDate`, since `new Date()` does not allow for you to input a variable timeZone. It only interprets UTC and the browser's local time.